# Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\Formulario de login\validar.php on line 10

Tags: base-de-datos, mysqli

```
<?php
$usuario=$_POST['usuario'];
$clave=$_POST['calve'];

//conectar a la base de datos
$conexion=mysqli_connect("localhost", "bdpureba");
$consulta="SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario='$usuario' and clave='$clave'";
$resultado=mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

$filas=mysqli_num_rows($resultado);

if ($filas>0) {
  header("location:Bienvenidos.html");
}
else {
  echo "Error en la autenticacion";
}
mysqli_free_result($resultado);
mysqli_close($conexion);
```

Comment: Es de hacer notar que esto no es Google, si quieres ayuda, necesitas redactar una pregunta, no copiar y pegar el error directamente. Formula una interrogante, da detalles sobre lo que quieres y sobre el error y se te ayudará

Comment: Jajajaja, de verdad lo siento, es mi primera vez que uso esta pagina para hacer una pregunta, a la proxima usare tus recomendaciones, gracias

Comment: Como la doy por resuelta ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes un error en la conexión. Las variables están erroneas, son declaradas con un nombre y llamadas con otro.

```
<?php
$usuario=$_POST['usuario'];
$clave=$_POST['calve']; // me imagino es clave?

//conectar a la base de datos
$conexion=mysqli_connect("localhost", "bdpureba"); imagino es bdprueba?
$consulta="SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario='$usuario' and clave='$clave'";
$resultado=mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

$filas=mysqli_num_rows($resultado);

if ($filas>0) {
  header("location:Bienvenidos.html");
}
else {
  echo "Error en la autenticacion";
}
mysqli_free_result($resultado);
mysqli_close($conexion);
```

Comment: Si, el error era otro pero de todas maneras ese tambien me afectaba, de todas manera gracias

Answer (score 1):

Lo que sucede es que la conexcion a la BD esta mal hecha, por ende nunca esta ejecutando la consulta y cuando vas a contar las filas, la Variable `$resultado` nunca esta siendo de tipo `mysqlli_resul`, qui te pongo un ejemplo del cual debes tomar:

```
<?php
$usuario=$_POST['usuario'];
$clave=$_POST['calve'];

//conectar a la base de datos
                          //host    //usuaruio = root   //si es root = ""  //nombre de la BD
$conexion=;mysqli_connect("localhost", "mi_usuario", "mi_contraseña", "bdpureba");
$consulta="SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario='$usuario' and clave='$clave'";
$resultado=mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

$filas=mysqli_num_rows($resultado);

if ($filas>0) {
  header("location:Bienvenidos.html");
}
else {
  echo "Error en la autenticacion";
}
mysqli_free_result($resultado);
mysqli_close($conexion);
```

espero te sirva Bro y como te dijeron antes, debes aprender a formular mejor las preguntas...ReNiceCOde...

Comment: Me sirvio mucho, muchas gracias, formulare mis preguntas a la proxima

Comment: @Jesús me alegra mucho Bro, marcala como resuelta, para las futuras generaciones tambien tome ayuda de esta, y espero la proxima vez sea mejor explicada XD ReNiceCode...